# Что делать с ошибкой listen EACCES: permission denied при запуске json-server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я создала два файла, `.jsx` и `.json`. И мне нужно запустить API, но при вводе команды запуска `json-server` выводится ошибка.

Команда запуска `json-server`:

```bsh
$ json-server --watch src/db_tab.json
```

Ошибка:

```
json-server --watch src/db_tab.json

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading src/db_tab.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/inventory

  Home
  http://localhost:3000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...

Some error occurred Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1301:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1503:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:8) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такие варианты:

- выключить приложение, которое в данный момент запущено на порту `3000`
- запустить своё приложение на другом порту `json-server ... -p 3001`

Comment: Порт 3001, как и 3002 прослушивался node,но я использовала порт 3003 и у меня всё получилось. Спасибо за совет